# Dice problem for the n space

Tags: permutations, combinations, dice

There is a 6-faced dice and every time you roll it, you move forward the same number of spaces that you rolled. If the finishing point is “n” spaces away from the starting point, how many possible ways are there to arrive exactly at the finishing point?

Comment: Is there a humorous intention in your title ? More seriously, what have you done on the subject before asking us ?

Comment: I did not in any way intend to be humorous or not serious. No offense, but I posted this problem because I had zero idea what to start with this problem. There are so many possibilities that I cannot come up with the appropriate formula for this. Do you have any concept I should know with regards to this problem?

Comment: Btw, I thought there was some humor in your title because it reminded me of n dimensional space.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions deals with the number of ["compositions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics) of an integer.

Although there is almost surely no closed form formula for it, here is a general technique for obtaining results for a given $n$ by using **generating functions**.

I will present it through an example: assume you want to reach position $n=12$ in $k=3$ steps, doing for example : $6+5+1$ or $5+6+1$ or $6+4+2$, etc. A hand examination show that there are 28 of them.

Let us now consider the following polynomial expansion:

$$p(x)^3 \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{with} \ \ \ \ \  p(x):=x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6$$

Using a Computer Algebra System like Mathematica, we obtain:

$$1 + 3\,x + 6\,x^2 + 10\,x^3 + 15\,x^4 + 21\,x^5 + 28\,x^6 + 33\,x^7 + 
  36\,x^8 + 37\,x^9 + 36\,x^{10} + 33\,x^{11} + 28\,x^{12} + 
  21\,x^{13} + 15\,x^{14} + 10\,x^{15} + 6\,x^{16} + 3\,x^{17} + 
  x^{18}.$$

The number of compositions of $n=12$ into $k$ parts is found directly as the coefficient 28 of $x^{12}$.

Explanation: The general term in the development of

$$(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)$$

is $x^{i+j+k},$ obtained by taking a $x^i$, a $x^j$, a $x^k$ in each of the three parentheses ; among all these $x^{i+j+k}$, keeping only those whose exponent $i+j+k$ is exactly $12$ amounts to "sweep" all "compositions" of $n=12$ into $k=3$  parts:

$$x^{6+5+1}+x^{5+6+1}+x^{6+4+2}+...$$

Keeping $n=12$ fixed, you now do these operations for all possible $k$, i.e., for all $k=3,4,...12$ (if course $k=1$ and $k=2$ are impossible).

Thus the answer is: the coefficient of $x^{12}$ in:

$$q(x)=p(x)^3+p(x)^4+\cdots+p(x)^{12}$$

which can also be written:

$$p(x)^3(1+p(x)+p(x)^2+\cdots+p(x)^9)=p(x)^3\dfrac{1-p(x)^{10}}{1-p(x)}$$

What has worked for $n=12$ will work of course for any other $n$...

Comment: can I consider x the same variable as n?

Comment: moreover, what is the idea behind is the polynomial function?

Comment: No "x" and "n" are two different things. "x" is a very artificial variable, just there for doing computations whereas "n" is very concrete (12) for example. By the way, seeing your 2nd question, may I ask what is your level of study and in which system of education, in order to answer you in an adequate way.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is the Pentanacci numbers. They're the generalization of the Fibonacci numbers defined by

```
a(n) = a(n-1) + a(n-2) + a(n-3) + a(n-4) + a(n-5)   // if n=5
a(n) = a(n-1) + a(n-2) + a(n-3) + a(n-4)            // if n=4
```

Reference: [oeis.org/A103814](http://oeis.org/A103814)

Python program to solve it:

```
def dice(n):
    A = 3**(n+6)
    M = A**6 - A**5 - A**4 - A**3 - A**2 - A - 1
    return pow(A, n+6, M) % A

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print dice(12)
    print dice(20)
    print dice(100)

# output: 
# 1936
# 463968
# 290078479914610587823630044098
```

Ruby program

```
def ways(n)
  return ways(n-1) + ways(n-2) + ways(n-3) + ways(n-4) + ways(n-5) + ways(n-6) if n >= 6
  return ways(4) + ways(3) + ways(2) + ways(1) + ways(0) if n == 5
  return ways(3) + ways(2) + ways(1) + ways(0) if n == 4
  return ways(2) + ways(1) + ways(0) if n == 3
  return ways(1) + ways(0) if n == 2
  return ways(0) if n == 1
  return 1 if n == 0
end

puts ways(ARGV[0].to_i)
```

Comment: It would be more helpful to explain what your program is doing, and why you chose to code it that way.

Comment: This problem is the Pentanacci numbers. They're the generalization of the Fibonacci numbers defined by a(n) = a(n-1) + a(n-2) + a(n-3) + a(n-4) + a(n-5) Reference: https://oeis.org/A103814

Comment: That's good - add it to your answer!